# Netbeans 7.3.1 autocomplete code on my Javascript Class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, web-applications, netbeans, ide

I have a question about autocomplete code for Javascript on Netbeans 7.3.1 for Mac. I have the following javascript code tha defines a class "Person":

```
function Person(nm, cgn, ss){
                 this.nome = nm;
                 this.cognome = cgn;
                 this.sesso = ss;

                 this.getNome = function(){
                    return nome;
                 };
                 this.getCognome = function(){
                    return cognome;
                 };
                 this.getSesso = function(){
                    return sesso;
                 };
              }
```

Under this code, if i try to write the following code:

```
var aPerson = new Person("C", "A", "p");
aPerson.get
```

I don't see (in autocomplete box) any function related to Person object.

Thanks.

Comment: I've just tested it with NetBeans 3.1, Win7. Works just fine. You can file a bug report over here -> https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=javascript

Comment: If it is a bug, can you tell me a good editor for HTML, CSS, Javascript for Mac? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of NetBeans.
Follow this step

1. Create a new file .js : `MyClass.js`
2. Insert class declaration in `MyClass.js`
3. Back to the .html and import the file `<script src = "MyClass.js">`

Now you can use the object MyClass with autocompletion.

Comment: In your EX, what if I have a project with say 12 javascript includes.  1 of those includes uses classes from other includes.  Does that mean netbeans can give me autocomplete in my JS file (not just index.html) for those other classes in the project?  I can't seem to get any member variables or methods in my JS code...frustrating having made nice data classes.  For one, how is it supposed to know what kind of variable type it is to match with the class file since JS is not strict types?  Does it parse for "new ____(*)" to recognize class instances and search for vars to offer as autocomplete?